# Installing python module issue

Tags: python-3.x, module, pip

I have successfully installed and used the requests module using PIP, however I have also installed the pyPdf and pyPDF2 modules but when i try and use these i am greeted with the error message no module called PDF found. As shown here 
https://gyazo.com/42d6dd39dd74ebcd993a5885b8a59c82
I've tried uninstalling python ive changed versions of python, ive replicated the problem on another computer, I've used the beta linux cli that's installed in windows to execute my program, which worked but I dont want to use linux and ontop of that I know when my lecturer marks the work she wont and will fail me as a result of it. 
Any help towards this end would be much appreciated 
OS is windows 10
Python 3 is used for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the module had pre-requisites that were not in the pip directories that needed to be installed beforehand. To find the list i just googled "InsertModuleNameHere requirements". Hope this helped